# Collapse a column

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataframe:

```
a   b   c
1   1   40
1   2   50
2   1   45
2   2   55
```

How can I collapse by a column?
Desired output:

```
a   b   c       c.b1    c.b2
1   1   40      40      50
1   2   50      40      50
2   1   45      45      55
2   2   55      45      55
```

I'm thinking I can merge somehow, but keep losing data and getting NA's out the other side

Comment: look into  package `reshape2`

Comment: It doesn't look like you are collapsing it by any column. You still have the same number of rows as in original data frame. Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 dfrm$c.b1 <- ave(dfrm$c, dfrm$a, FUN=function(x) x[1])
 # returns [1] 40 40 45 45
 dfrm$c.b2 <- ave(dfrm$c, dfrm$a, FUN=function(x) x[2])
 # returns [1] 50 50 55 55
```

Note that the indexing factor was the "a" column to get the result (rather than agreeing with the label). If it turns out that you have a more complex problem then your data example should be modified to illustrate what the real problem might be.

Comment: WOW! thank you so much! I have been running in circles on this for days.